# Saving PDF "Blobs" in Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

I'm trying to populate a folder with a list of pdf documents I've created using Google Scripts.  But when I obtain a PDF file, which I guess is a "Blob", I can't find any functionality to move this file to a specified folder.  Ultimately I would like to do something like this:

```
  var temp = target.getAs("application/pdf");
  var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolder(TARGET_FOLDER);

  temp.addToFolder(targetFolder);
```

Unfortunately addToFolder is not a thing.  Is there anyway to accomplish this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The folder object has a [createFile()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/folder#createFile(BlobSource)) method that takes a blob as argument.

use it like this :

```
  var temp = target.getAs("application/pdf");
  var targetFolder = DocsList.getFolderById('0B3qS__folder ID____dsMTFZMDQ')
  targetFolder.createFile(temp);// this will create the pdf file directly in the folder
```

Comment: You, my friend, are fantastic.  Thank you.